# How can I sort keys and values in Map in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, set

I am trying to get the key that has maximum value in the `map` which I have created through `new Map()` and added the keys & values in it.

Now, I wanted to get the key whose value is maximum and if two keys have the same values then I want to return the lexicographically largest.

For eg: `{'a': 20, 'b':20}` then I want `b` to be return.

my code:

```
var slowestKey = function(releaseTimes, keysPressed) {
    let map=new Map();
     map.set(keysPressed[0],releaseTimes[0]);  
    for(let i=0; i<releaseTimes.length-1; i++){
         let time=releaseTimes[i+1]-releaseTimes[i];
            map.set(keysPressed[i+1],time);
    }
    let max= Math.max(...map.values());
    console.log(map)
    console.log(Math.max(...map.values()));
    
};
```

Input:

```
Input: releaseTimes = [9,29,49,50], keysPressed = "cbcd"
```

`Expected Output: "c"`

console.log:

```
Map(3) { 'c' => 20, 'b' => 20, 'd' => 1 }
20
```

How can I get the key whose value is maximum and lexicographically bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `filter` you can filter the `keys` whose value = `max` value, then you can `sort`, and get the first item.

So, the extra code will be

```
const [key] = [...map.keys()].filter(key => {
      return map.get(key) === max
 }).sort((a, b) => a - b)
```

```js
var slowestKey = function(releaseTimes, keysPressed) {
    let map=new Map();
     map.set(keysPressed[0],releaseTimes[0]);  
    for(let i=0; i<releaseTimes.length-1; i++){
         let time=releaseTimes[i+1]-releaseTimes[i];
            map.set(keysPressed[i+1],time);
    }
    let max= Math.max(...map.values());
    const [key] = [...map.keys()].filter(key => {
      return map.get(key) === max
    }).sort((a, b) => a - b)
    console.log(key)
};


slowestKey([9,29,49,50], "cbcd")
```

Comment: And, how can I sort lexicographically in array. Like `['abc', 'bc']` to `['cba','cb']` ?

Comment: You can use this.  `const arr = ['abc', 'bc']; const result = arr.map(i => i.split('').sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a)).join('')).sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a))`

Answer (score 2):

By having an array of key/value pairs, you could sort by

- value descending
- key descending

and take the first pair (index `0`).

```js
const
    pairs = [['c', 9], ['b', 29], ['c', 49], ['d', 50], ['a', 50]];

pairs.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1] || b[0].localeCompare(a[0]));

console.log(pairs[0]);
```

Comment: And, how can I sort lexicographically in array. Like `['abc', 'bc']` to `['cba','cb']` ?

Comment: just with `sort()`.